# Joining two lists with common elements - Scala

Tags: list, scala, join

I have 2 Lists as mentioned below:

```
val L1 = List[(Int,Int,String)]
val L2 = List[(Int,Int,String)]
```

I want to join these 2 lists on the basis of 1st and 2nd Int element in a way that result list must have 4 elements (Int,Int,String,String).

```
val joinedList = List[(Int, Int, String, String)]
```

where last 2 String elements will be string from L1 and string from L2.

Ex:-

```
val L1 = List((1,1,"one"), (2,2,"two"))
val L2 = List((2,2,"twice"), (3,3,"thrice"))
```

Output List ->

```
val joinedList = List((1,1,"one","--"),(2,2,"two","twice"), (3,3,"--","thrice"))
```

Kindly suggest a way to achieve that in scala.

Comment: I could not think of a way to do it as even with 'zip', could only combine the lists.

Comment: This will take a bit more effort then `zip`. Check out `.groupBy`. You need to use that to convert one of the lists into a map where you can look up the data easily. Then `.map` the other list, look for matching data in the map, and add it to each element.

Comment: What determines the order of the resulting list? Everything in list one, followed by non-matching from list2? Or something else? @Dima has given you an approach but you also need to consider items in the list you converted to a map that are not in the other list.

Comment: @Dima will try with your approach as well and update, if that works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you want to get it into `Maps`, so it's easier to look up, then you can just `map` over all the keys:

```
val L1Map = L1.map{case (x,y,z) => ((x,y) -> z)}.toMap
val L2Map = L2.map{case (x,y,z) => ((x,y) -> z)}.toMap
val allKeys = L1Map.keySet ++ L2Map.keySet

val result = allKeys map {case (x,y) =>
  (x, y, L1Map.getOrElse((x,y), "--"), L2Map.getOrElse((x,y), "--"))
}
```

That gives you an unsorted `Set` as a result.  If you need a `List`, you can convert it back and sort it as necessary.